# Drawing border of constant width around image in OpenGL on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

I am trying to draw a border around an image that is rendered using **OpenGL** on an **Android** and **iOS** app. The way I do it now is that I specify the 3 vertices around each corner of the image as shown in the diagram and fill them up by drawing triangles.

[image: image link]

The way I compute these vertices is by adding/subtracting an absolute value called **BORDER_WIDTH** that is set to a float. For example, the  3 vertices around the left corner of the rendered image (marked as 0,1,2 in the image linked above) are computed as follows.

```
[bottom_left_viewport_vertex[0] - BORDER_WIDTH, bottom_left_viewport_vertex[1], 0.0f,
bottom_left_viewport_vertex[0] - BORDER_WIDTH, bottom_left_viewport_vertex[1] - BORDER_WIDTH, 0.0f,
bottom_left_viewport_vertex[0], bottom_left_viewport_vertex[1] - BORDER_WIDTH, 0.0f]
```

This method causes 2 problems:

1. The border is way thicker on iOS devices compared to Android devices probably because of the **Retina** display.
2. The width of the border on the **top** and the **bottom** of the image is different from that on the **sides** of the image.

What is the right way to solve such a problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you searching for something like [OpenGL Line Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484260/opengl-line-width/59688394#59688394)?

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76 for your help. I am an OpenGL newbie and still have to understand your method fully and adapt it to what I have. But first I'm going to try what solidpixel suggested to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The border is way thicker on iOS devices compared to Android devices probably because of the Retina display.

Determine the DPI using DisplayMetrics, and adjust your BORDER_WIDTH value as appropriate.

> The width of the border on the top and the bottom of the image is different from that on the sides of the image.

Viewport coordinates are between zero and one, regardless of aspect ratio. If you're not correcting for aspect ratio, then everything is going to get scaled by that.

Alternatively, you are doing calculations assuming pixels are square. They usually aren't.

Comment: Hi @solidpixel. I'm still not clear how I can correct for aspect ratio, as you mentioned above. Could you provide some hints please.

Comment: Clip-space vertex coordinates out of the vertex shader are between -1 and 1 in the viewport. If you apply the same increment of "border width" applied in clipspace, that will get scaled by the viewport size to generate pixel coordinates. Unless your viewport is square, applying the same clip-space increment to each vertex won't work.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you are setting this up - you only posted an incomplete code extract with no context.