# How to calculate the vertex indices for the outline of a shape?

Tags: 2d, shapes, vertex, index-buffer

I want to calculate the indices necessary to draw the outline of a shape using clockwise winding. The example uses a square but it could be any regular polygon.

Given a square with vertices `0, 1, 2, 3`, it can be drawn with indices `0, 1, 2` and `0, 2, 3`. The outline vertices are the same 4 vertices as the original square (`4, 5, 6, 7`) plus 4 more (`8, 9, 10, 11`) some distance and direction from the original vertices.

[image: Square with labelled vertices]

The code below calculates the relevant indices for the outline and appends them to the indices for the original shape. For the example square, the outline indices are as follows:

```
4, 8, 9,
4, 9, 5,
5, 9, 10,
5, 10, 6,
6, 10, 11,
6, 11, 7,
7, 11, 8,
7, 8, 4
```

```
fn update_outline_vertices(&mut self) {
    let point_count = self.point_count();
    let inner_vertex_count = 4;
    let inner_index_count = (point_count - 2) * 3;

    if self.outline_thickness == 0.0 {
        // Resize.
        return;
    }

    let outline_vertex_count = inner_vertex_count * 2;
    let vertex_count = inner_vertex_count + outline_vertex_count;
    let index_count = inner_index_count + outline_vertex_count * 3;
    self.vertices.resize(vertex_count);
    self.indices.resize(index_count, 0);

    for i in 0..point_count {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973103/how-to-create-outline?noredirect=1&lq=1
        let p = if i == 0 { point_count - 1 } else { i - 1 };

        let p1 = self.point(p);
        let p2 = self.point(i);
        let p3 = self.point(i + 1);

        let outline_point = calculate_outline_point(p1, p2, p3, self.outline_thickness);

        self.vertices[point_count + i].position = p2;
        self.vertices[2 * point_count + i].position = outline_point;

        // Build outline indices.
        let offset = inner_index_count + i * 6;
        self.indices[offset] = (i + point_count) as u32;
        self.indices[offset + 1] = ((i + point_count) + point_count) as u32;
        self.indices[offset + 2] =
            (((i + point_count + 1) % point_count + point_count) + point_count) as u32;
        self.indices[offset + 3] = (i + point_count) as u32;
        self.indices[offset + 4] =
            (((i + point_count + 1) % point_count + point_count) + point_count) as u32;
        self.indices[offset + 5] = (((i + 1) % point_count) + point_count) as u32;
    }
}
```

However, there's a lot going on with the modulo and multiple `point_count`'s when calculating each index and it's not exactly obvious what is going on or why. What is a more common algorithm to calculate these outline points?